# Entity Framework - Detach Object and Reattach

Tags: c#, entity

I have to insert several entities to a database which hold references to other entities already present in the database e.g:

```
Order tmpOrder = new tmpOrder();
Order.Position.Add(tmpPosition);
```

The tmpPosition-Object is fetched from another context so in course to insert the object into the database I have to detach the tmpPosition-Object from its former context.

Unfortunately afterwards the the tmpPosition-Object is not accessible anymore. Is there any way I can detach the ReferenceObject and reattach it after inserting my new object into the database?

I'm using Entity Framework Version 4.1.

Comment: It´s been some time but i found a solution to this problem by using a wrapper class which holds all needed references.